# Binding a child Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a nested gridview and its editable. Although its using access as its datasource for testing purposes I want to deploy it with mysql datasource. I have realized that something is wrong. My Gridview has to show when search is clicked.
This is my original access datasource code:

```
//This procedure prepares the query to bind the child GridView
private AccessDataSource ChildDataSource(string strCustometId, string strSort)
{
    string strQRY = "";
    AccessDataSource dsTemp = new AccessDataSource();
    dsTemp.DataFile = "App_Data/BV.mdb";
    strQRY = "Query statement";

    dsTemp.SelectCommand = strQRY;
    return dsTemp;
}
```

I changed to accomodate MySql users.

```
private SqlDataSource ChildDataSource(string strCustometId, string strSort)
{
    string strQRY = "";
    SqlDataSource dsTemp = new SqlDataSource();
    dsTemp.ID = "dsTemp";

   string sCon= WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bv"].ConnectionString;
   dsTemp.ConnectionString = sCon;
    strQRY = "Query stament here";
dsTemp.SelectCommand = strQRY;
    return dsTemp;
}
```

This is my connection string from web.config.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="bv" connectionString="server=localhost;database=cms;Connect Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=False;User id = root;password=xxxxx" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

The second code gives errors and says Login failed for user 'root'. There is something wrong with my connection string and datasource code. I am inexperienced and please need help in this.

Comment: You need to show us your connection string.  You can check [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) for examples, there are a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have edited code. Checked the connectionString.com site as well and used the guideline from them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that SQL Server has a login for the user 'root' with the password that you have specified in your connection string, and also that the user 'root' has the necessary priveleges to access objects in the 'cms' database.

Comment: I am not using SQL Server. I am using Mysql.

Comment: @SitheloNgwenya Is it okay to a use a SqlDataSource to connect to MySQL?  I thought that just connected to SQL Server, but I could be wrong.  I don't use MySQL.

Comment: The SqlDataSource only connects to SQL Server. If you are using MySQL then you will need to use an OleDbDataSource instead.

Comment: I have .NET connector and this enables me to connect to MySql. I installed it prior to using the SqlDataSource component

Comment: Yes, after a bit of reading I discovered that you can use a SqlDataSource with MySQL with the appropriate connector - nice! Have you checked that the password for user root that you have specified in your connection string is the correct password?, and also that the user root has at least select privileges on the cms database?